# Process / Etiquette around promoting a tag(s) to form a community

Tags: discussion, tags, area-51

I know that suggesting a community happens in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), but in addition to that does the Stack Overflow team/community ever suggest that a tag (or a group of tags/other communities) should evolve into one community? Basically to clean up Stack Overflow a bit.

Let me give you an example. The main reason I frequent here is due to C# coding questions, but I also work a lot with a platform called Dynamics 365 (formerly Dynamics CRM: [dynamics-crm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm)). The questions around this on Stack Overflow frequently cross a line into a vast grey area, an area where 1it can be questioned whether or not it is a coding question any more.

Others go beyond and are not development-related at all. Here's an example where I think it's crossed the line into "not a development question": *[New entity or customize the existing entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636520/new-entity-or-customize-the-existing-entity)*. This isn't a coding question; it's a platform question.

But in fairness, and unless I'm mistaken, there's no real place on Stack Exchange to ask a question like this. So Stack Overflow becomes a bit of a dumping ground.

[salesforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/salesforce) seems to have used Stack Overflow as a similar dumping ground as well, but here is where it gets even more complicated. They have their own [salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.

Similarly, [sitecore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/) / [sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore) is in a similar position.

So, sometimes I feel like we're missing a site called "platform development" or something, where these type of questions should go. Or, possibly a specific community for "Dynamics" which directs all the traffic to that community instead? (similar to *[Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)* and *[Sitecore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/)). To be honest, I think they all should share a site called platforms or something; it's not like C# has its own site on here. Which brings me back to my question.

Do these types of tags and communities eventually get bundled up and a new community suggested in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)? And if so, what's the etiquette and/or process of discussing and doing so? I don't want to go willy nilly suggesting communities just for the sake of doing so and end up blown out of the water.

And also, if you don't quite know what to suggest for these tags / communities, where do those discussions go before you suggest a site in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)?

(PS: I did search, and failed, so apologies if this was already asked...)

Comment: Yes, belongs on Area51.  There is one that tries to cover Dynamics: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/103896/erp-software

Comment: I think the proposal missed the bill a bit. Which gives me more reason to ask the question about the discussion process. ERP is a specific type or genre of platform. Dynamics 365 for example is a combination of 2 types of platforms, ERP and CRM. Maybe I should contribute to that topic!